# Browser only sets the first cookie out of multiple comma-separated cookies

Tags: cookies, http-headers

I'm manually creating a header of `set-cookie` and I want to set multiple cookies. Here's what the header looks like:

```bash
set-cookie: cookie-a=value-a; domain=.company.com; path=/; httponly, cookie-b=value-b;  domain=.company.com; path=/; httponly
```

The problem is that the browser sets the first cookie, but not the second cookie. How can I get the browser to also set the second cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Some HTTP header only allow a single value, but the HTTP headers that do support multiple values use comma-separated values. For example:
`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE.`

The `set-cookies` header is one of the few (if not the only) exception to this rule!

To set multiple cookies, you set the same header multiple times:

```bash
set-cookie: cookie-a=value-a; domain=.company.com; path=/; httponly
set-cookie: cookie-b=value-b;  domain=.company.com; path=/; httponly
```

If you try to use a comma-separated list, the browser will read the first cookie and assume everything after it are just cookie attributes. For any attributes it doesn't recognize, it will just ignore without throwing any errors. The result is that your first cookie is set correctly, and all other are ignored. Yikes!